X-ray mode not working in certain workspaces
I have a strange problem and I don't know where I'm going wrong I'm sure I'm missing something rather obvious but it's driving me mad.
X-ray mode appears to not work in material and render preview viewport shading modes, but only in specific workspaces. I can see the geometry selected in my 'UV Editing' workspace here:

This is with all vertices selected, in edit mode, X-ray toggled on, and with the scene world and scene lights ticked off.
Yet here is the exact same scene, in edit mode, with X-ray toggled on, and with the scene world and scene lights ticked off, the only difference (as far as I know) is the workspace has changed:

As you can (not)see, the vertices are no longer visible. This is the case for render preview mode as well. X-ray mode is still working as expected in Solid and Wireframe viewport shading modes.
Any idea what I could be missing?

As far as i know this is the expected behaviour. X-Ray mode is only supported in Solid and Wireframe, as stated by blender:


That notification shows in Object mode, not Edit mode. X-ray mode has worked in material and render preview mode before, and as I said it IS currently working, just not in one particular workspace.
